# "10 years in" vs. "In 10 years"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I read a headline: "10 years in, something happens". Is that grammatically correct or incorrect to give that headline? Any difference with "In 10 years, something happens"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*10 years in* = after 10 years (have/had elapsed).

*In 10 years* = 10 years (later) from now.

Comment: Is it correct to use "In 10 years, something has happened"?

Comment: No!  The perfect tense is used for the near-present, for example, "*I have (just) brushed my teeth*. '***In 10 years...***' is talking about the (10-years-away) future, for example, *"In 10 years, God willing, I will be able to play Rachmaninov's 3rd piano concerto"*.

Answer (score 0):

In "10 years in", "in" is an adverb, not a preposition. I read it as meaning "into the project". I would find it an odd usage if the project had already finished before the ten years.

Answer (score 0):

The word **in** can refer to a stretch of space or a stretch of time. **In** can refer to that stretch as one that has not yet been traversed, or **in** can refer to that stretch as one which has already been crossed.  When **in** is at the front of the phrase, the stretch lies ahead.  When **in** is at the back of the phrase, that stretch lies behind.

> Today we are going to take you to a Mayan pyramid. This road leads into the jungle. *In five miles*, we will see a pyramid.

They are at the edge of the jungle. Five miles *ahead*, there will be a pyramid.

> They entered the jungle. *Five miles in*, they saw a Mayan pyramid.

They entered the jungle and then drove for five miles. After driving file miles, they saw a pyramid.

in five miles .... five miles ahead

five miles in .... having come five miles